# central.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices:[SERVICE_UUID]) returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a BLE reconnection logic that first retrieves connected device using a specific service UUID, if not found, then retrieve the previous connected device with the stored peripheral UUID. If no peripheral UUID found, then central manager would scan and discover with the same service UUID. However, scan works and the central manager is able to discover the peripheral. But if trigger reconnection from the app, in which case BLE is still connected on OS level(shown as connected in iOS BT settings), central.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices:[SERVICE_UUID]) does not return anything.

Is there anything I'm missing to make central.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices:[SERVICE_UUID]) returns the connected peripherals with SERVICE_UUID?

Here's the relevant code:

```swift
    // master function to control the connection logic
    private func connect(with peripheralIdentifier: String) {
        // connectedPeripheral is always nil even when BLE is connected on OS level
        if let connectedPeripheral = retrieveConnectedPeripheral(forIdentifier: peripheralIdentifier) {
            logger.d("peripheral is already connected in OS, establishing local connection...")
            self.peripheral = peripheral
            central.connect(connectedPeripheral, options: nil)
            return
        }

        if let peripheral = retrievePeripheral(forIdentifier: peripheralIdentifier) {
            logger.d("peripheral was previous connected, attempting to reconnect...")
            self.peripheral = peripheral
            central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
            return
        }

        // start scan only when peripheral was never connected
        startPairing()
    }

    private func retrieveConnectedPeripheral(forIdentifier uuid: String) -> CBPeripheral? {
        return central
            .retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: [SERVICE_UUID])
            .first
    }

    private func retrievePeripheral(forIdentifier uuid: String) -> CBPeripheral? {
        let p = central.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: [uuid]).first
        logger.d("retrieved peripheral has services \(p?.services)") // it's always [], even when peripheral.discoverServices is called in didConnect callback
        return p
    }
    private func startPairing() {
        central.scanForPeripherals(
            withServices: [
                SERVICE_UUID
            ],
            options: nil)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,
                        didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                        advertisementData: [String: Any],
                        rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        if foundPeripheral(peripheral.name) {
            logger.d("""
                discovered a matching peripheral with \(String(describing: peripheral.name)),
                UUID \(peripheral.identifier),
                advertisementData \(advertisementData.description)
                """)
            self.peripheral = peripheral
            self.central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,
                        didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        let uuid = peripheral.identifier
        // stores the UUID for reconnection 
        setPeripheralUuid(forKey: identifier, uuid: uuid)
        peripheral.delegate = self
        // calling this because the Developer Doc says without this, peripheral.services will be []. But after calling this, it's still []
        peripheral.discoverServices([SERVICE_UUID])
        stopScan()
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        if error == nil {
            logger.d("discovered services: \(peripheral.services)") // falls into this case, but it's []
        } else {
            logger.e("Failed to discover service for \(peripheral)!", error)
        }
    }
```

As mentioned in the code comments, not sure if central.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices:[SERVICE_UUID]) returns nothing is related to peripheral.services returns nothing. It's possible that there is something obvious that I'm missing t

Comment: If you know the peripheral identifier you are better off using [`retrievePeripherals`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1519127-retrieveperipherals)

Comment: @Paulw11 I agree and it's been working fine for me. However, a new use case is added that I don't see any workaround. I've been scratching my head for this for quite a while.